# RegEx help for chess moves (SAN)

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a program that should be able to read and parse chess moves ([SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess))).

Here's an example of possible accepted moves:

```
e4
Nf3
Nbd2
Nb1c3
R1a3
d8=Q
exd5
Nbxd2
...
```

I first wrote the [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), then converted it to grammar and then I converted it to a regular expression.

With my conventions, this is how it looks

```
pln + plxln + plnxln + plnln + plln + pxln + lxln=(B+R+Q+N) + lxln + lnxln=(B+R+Q+N) + lnxln + lnln=(B+R+Q+N) + lnln + ln=(B+R+Q+N) + ln + pnxln + pnln
```

where:

`p` is a character of set `{B,R,Q,N,K}` (or think it as `(B+R+Q+N+K)` = `[BRQNK]`

`l` is a character among `[a-h]` interval (case sensitive)

`n` is a number among `[1-8]` interval

`+` represents Union operation... if I got it right, `(B+R+Q+N)` is `[BRQN]` in regex's programming languages.

`=` is just a normal character... in chess moves it's used in promotion (ex. e8=Q)

`x` is a normal character too... used when by moving your piece in that location you're taking an opponent's one.

`(`/`)`: Like in math

I tried to parse first part `pln` as: `[BRQN][a-h][1-8]` in an online java regex tester and worked for a move like `Nf3`. I didn't get well how to do the union thing for composite expression (like `pln+plxln`)... also how can I label to parts of regex so that when it's detected, I get all the infos? I tried to read docs about it but didn't figure out.

Any advice?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have to take care of castling, check and checkmate?

Comment: I have to do the castling yet (though could be written in the expression as a "O-O" string or "O-O-O".. Check and checkmate can be a nice feature but are not strictly required in my program... though they don't seem hard to add... but would make expression longer. I see if I write the expression more completely

Comment: Update: I've seen that ChessBase ignores symbols like + or # put out place (not check/mate) as not necessary, indeed a program should be able to understand when a check/mate is made.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` in your notation is `|` in regexes. So you could use the regex

```
[BRQNK][a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h]x[a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h][1-8]x[a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h][1-8][a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h][a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK]x[a-h][1-8]|[a-h]x[a-h][1-8]=(B+R+Q+N)|[a-h]x[a-h][1-8]|[a-h][1-8]x[a-h][1-8]=(B+R+Q+N)|[a-h][1-8]x[a-h][1-8]|[a-h][1-8][a-h][1-8]=(B+R+Q+N)|[a-h][1-8][a-h][1-8]|[a-h][1-8]=(B+R+Q+N)|[a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][1-8]x[a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][1-8][a-h][1-8]
```

This is, clearly, a bit ugly. I can think of 2 possible ways to make it nicer:

- With the [`COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) flag, you can add whitespace.
- Combine the possibilities together in a nicer way. For example, `[BRQNK][a-h]x[a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h][1-8]x[a-h][1-8]` can be rewritten as `[BRQNK][a-h][1-8]?x[a-h][1-8]`.

I also know of one other improvement which isn't available in java. (And maybe not many languages, but you can do it in Perl.) The subexpression `(?1)` (likewise `(?2)`, etc) is a bit like `\1`, except that instead of matching the exact string that matched the first capture group, it matches any string that could have matched that capture group. In other words, it's equivalent to writing the capture group out again. So you could (in Perl) replace the first `[BRQNK]` with `([BRQNK])`, then replace all subsequent occurrences with `(?1)`.

Comment: Yeah! This actually recognizes moves! I also need to sub-analyze moves, and I was wondering if naming in groups would make it. I thought something like `(?<P>[BRQNK])(?<dl>[a-h])(?<dn>[1-8])|(?<P>[BRQNK].....`, where `P` stands as Piece, `dl` as destination letter, `dn` as destination number, and for other types of move `ol` and `od` (o = origin). Problem is that I can't give same name twice for groups even if in the match they will never be found together... How can I do it? In the end I'd need at least 3 variables per move, and more when details are added (like column specification)

Comment: I can't think of a better way to do it in java. You could of course use slightly different names for equivalent capture groups. Still slightly nicer than numbered groups. (In Perl I would say you could use the `(?|...)` group, except that it doesn't play nicely with named capture groups unless the group names are the same in all alternatives.)

Answer (score 2):

`/^([NBRQK])?([a-h])?([1-8])?(x)?([a-h][1-8])(=[NBRQK])?(\+|#)?$|^O-O(-O)?$/`

---

.

.

.

.

This was unit tested against 2599 cases. See below for unit tests

```
describe('Importer/Game', function() {
    let Importer, Game;
    beforeEach(function() {
        Importer = require(`${moduleDir}/import`).Importer;
        Game = require(`${moduleDir}/import`).Game;
    });
    describe('moveRegex', function() {
        describe('non-castling', function() {
            //  ([NBRQK])?  ([a-h])?   ([1-8])?   (x)?     ([a-h][1-8]) (=[NBRQK])? (+|#)?/
            //  unitType?   startFile? startRank? capture? end          promotion?  checkState?
            for(let unitType of ['', 'N', 'B', 'R', 'Q', 'K']) {
                for(let startFile of ['', 'b']) {
                    for(let startRank of ['', '3']) {
                        for(let capture of ['', 'x']) {
                            for(let promotion of ['', '=Q']) {
                                for(let checkState of ['', '+', '#']) {
                                    //TODO: castling
                                    const dest = 'e4';
                                    const san = unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + dest + promotion + checkState;
                                    testPositive(san);
                                    //TODO: negative substitutions here.
                                    testNagative('Y'      + startFile + startRank + capture + dest + promotion + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + 'i'       + startRank + capture + dest + promotion + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + '9'       + capture + dest + promotion + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + 'X'     + dest + promotion + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + 'i9' + promotion + checkState);
                                    // testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + ''   + promotion + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + dest + '='       + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + dest + 'Q'       + checkState);
                                    testNagative(unitType + startFile + startRank + capture + dest + promotion + '++');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        describe('castling', function() {
            testPositive('O-O');
            testPositive('O-O-O');
            testNagative('OOO');
            testNagative('OO');
            testNagative('O-O-');
            testNagative('O-O-O-O');
            testNagative('O');
        });
        function testPositive(san) {
            it(`should handle this san: ${san}`, function(done) {
                const matches = san.match(Importer.moveRegex);
                assert(matches);
                done();
            });
        }
        function testNagative(san) {
            it(`should not match this: ${san}`, function(done) {
                const matches = san.match(Importer.moveRegex);
                assert(!matches);
                done();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Re: /^([NBRQK])?([a-h])?([1-8])?(x)?([a-h][1-8])(=[NBRQK])?(\+|#)?$|^O-O(-O)?$/
```

It's both underinclusive and overinclusive.

It excludes the possibly legal moves `O-O+, O-O-O+, O-O#, and O-O-O#.`

It includes many strings that can never be legal: `e8=K, Kaa4, Nf5=B, Qa1xb7`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this one:

```
/(^([PNBRQK])?([a-h])?([1-8])?(x|X|-)?([a-h][1-8])(=[NBRQ]| ?e\.p\.)?|^O-O(-O)?)(\+|\#|\$)?$/
```

Includes: `O-O+`, `O-O-O+`, `O-O#` and `O-O-O#`

Also: `e.p.`, `N-f6` or `NXf6` and `Pe4` or `Pe5xd6`

**Update:**

Thanks @Toto for improving my version of regex above:

```
^([PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?[xX-]?[a-h][1-8](=[NBRQ]| ?e\.p\.)?|^O-O(?:-O)?)[+#$]?$
```

Comment: Why all these capture groups?

Comment: @Toto i use it in my program. It's optional, u can say e4 or explicit the pawn: Pe4

Comment: No, your regex is **not** optional, it takes `2.0 ms` and `268 steps` to match your 8 examples. When you remove the useless capture groups, it takes `1.0 ms` and `146 steps` to complete. [Proof](https://regex101.com/r/0ib12B/1)

Comment: @Toto I still needed those capture groups if the input was for example [Long Algebraic Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#Long_algebraic_notation)

Comment: Have you looked at the link I've provided above? The simplefied regex matches **all** your examples and it's twice more efficient.

Comment: @Toto Yeah, you are right

Comment: @Toto Your version is faster and better but i need to parse SAN in my code in C#, so I "split" the input using capture groups... Anyway thanks bro

Answer (score -1):

I have been using this for a while in my web portal.

```
[BRQNK][a-h][1-8]| [a-h][1-8]|[BRQNK][a-h][a-h][1-8]|O-O|0-0-0|[BRQNK]x[a-h][1-8]|[a-h]x[a-h][1-8]|1\/2-1\/2|1\/-O|O-\/1
```